# How to use pfx, crt and key files to connect to Java Spring boot server

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, pkcs#12

We have received crt, pfx and key file from our server team which is a Spring boot application. These are not self signed certificates.

Now, we are requested to use the certificates and change our code to our server application via HTTPs.

Can some one please advice how to load these certificates and establish the connection with Java server application.

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial? What have you tried so far? What hasn't been working the way you expect?

Comment: I am looking for a tutorial. Most of the tutorial is self signed and not between a real server and client. Kindly help if you have some reference tutorial.